# C++ "list iterator error"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, list

I'm having a problem with the following section of code. I've worked with this for a bit and have found the issue comes in `*pos` is added. I'm just not sure how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

list<int>:: iterator pos;           //iterator for pos to allow movement through the list
list<int> numbers;                  // list of int's called "numbers"
int a;                              //  @param a: int to store value at the current position in the list for comparison
int b = 0;                          //  @param b: int to store larger value after comparison



/*function maximum cycles through the list of numbers and assigns the number at each position to variable a
variable a is then compared to variable b which holds the largest element, if variable a is larger than b then
variable a's value is given to b.
*/


int maximum()
{

        for (pos = numbers.begin(); pos != numbers.end(); pos++)
        {
            a = *pos;
                if (a > b)
                {
                    b = a;
                }
        } 

return b; 
}


int main()
{

    int UserNum;        //@param UserNum are the numbers the user will enter that will be added to the list


    //A do loop to fill the list with numbers entered by the user.
    cout << "Enter some numbers (0 to end)" << endl;
    do 
    {
        cin >> UserNum;
        numbers.push_back (UserNum);
    }
    while (UserNum);


    maximum();

    cout << ("Your largest element entered is ") << b << endl;


    system ("PAUSE");
```

Comment: What is the type of `pos`?

Comment: its a list of numbers

Comment: Where `a` and `b` are declared?

Comment: `list<int>:: iterator pos;   
list<int> numbers;     
int a;         
int b = 0;`

Comment: Some correct answers already.  Worth noting that you would have had a (helpful) compiler error if you'd defined `pos` within the `for` statement (`for (auto pos = ` or `for (list<int>::iterator pos =`) instead of using a global....

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: it's a run-time error : Expression: list iterator not dereferencable

Comment: I just copied your code and compiled using g++ for C++11 and it ran fine. Try cleaning your project and rebuilding it completely.
Maybe you have a compiled object that is not updating.

Comment: I cannot believe this...there was something wrong with the project window I was working with...I loaded it into a new project and it worked...thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon from the end of this line.

```
 for (pos = numbers.begin(); pos != numbers.end(); pos++) ;
```

Comment: thanks, still getting the error. I've tried various ways and the error only shows up when i add `*pos`.

Comment: I commented out that section and just ran a `cout` statement in the function and it worked fine so something with the `*pos` isn't right just can't put my finger on what.

Comment: Show the declarations for numbers, pos, a and b.

Comment: It should work as is, I've compiled and tested it. Are you sure you have tested the code shown above?

Comment: could it just be my VS? I cut and pasted that out right out of VS and tested after fixing the extra ;...it will compile but when you hit 0 it errors

Comment: I cannot believe this...there was something wrong with the project window I was working with...I loaded it into a new project and it worked...thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have a semicolon at the end of your `for` statement

```
for (pos = numbers.begin(); pos != numbers.end(); pos++) ;
                                                        ^^^
```

Remove that and your code should work.

---

**EDIT:**

Note that if your list is empty, the returned iterator value cannot be dereferenced, which could be the cause of your runtime error. So if you run your code and enter `0` immediately before adding any numbers, you'll get the error you're seeing.

Comment: still get the error, I commented out the `*pos` and added a `cout` statement and it didn't error. Could `pos` be trying to get out of bounds such as trying to reference `numbers.end()`?

Comment: it's a run-time error : Expression: list iterator not dereferencable

Comment: I've added more detail to the answer.